# MPI_Comm_spawn throws Assertion failed in file src/util/procmap/local_proc.c at line 127: node_id <= max_node_id

Tags: c++, mpi, spawn, mpich

I am using MPICH. I start a mpi program with one process, using:

```
mpiexec -n 1 -f hostfile ./master [arguments]
```

Where my arguments are the set of arguments required by the mpi process. The master calculates the optimal number of worker processes to be spawned and then calls the following function:

```
MPI_Comm_spawn("./worker", argv, nprocs, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,&intercomm,NULL);
```

Now this program works fine when I have a machinefile looks like:

```
node01:2
node02:1
node03:1
node04:1
```

So on node01 I have 2 processes running (master + 1 worker) and the rest of the nodes have one process.However, I want each node to run only 1 process. So I modified the hostfile is as follows. Now after the `MPI_COMM_spawn()`, the child processes aren't initialized and I end up with an assertion failed.

```
node01:1
node02:1
node03:1
node04:1
```

**ERROR**

```
Assertion failed in file src/util/procmap/local_proc.c at line 127: node_id <= max_node_id
internal ABORT - process 0
Assertion failed in file src/util/procmap/local_proc.c at line 112: my_node_id <= max_node_id
internal ABORT - process 2
Assertion failed in file src/util/procmap/local_proc.c at line 127: node_id <= max_node_id
internal ABORT - process 1
```

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong in this case. Has anyone else faced a similar issue? What is the probable cause of it?

Comment: What is the value of `nprocs`? There must be enough process slots in the hostfile for both MPI jobs, i.e. `nprocs + 1` slots.

Comment: In this case I am getting `nprocs` equal to 3.